# Adding a resultset to an existing result set

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to execute a query on the database within a do while loop and keep on adding to the resultset. However once its finished running all the queries and I then start processing the result set php gives the error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   string given in

The idea is it executes a query with a limit of 0,2 then executes again with a limit of 2,2 and so on until the numbers of rows returned is empty. I know the best solution would be to do a count and work out from there but this is not an option as the database is too large.

Below is the code that I currently have

```
    $tempResult = "";
    $i = 0;
    $result = null;
    do
    {
        if (is_resource($tempResult))
        {
            echo 'Cleared Result <br />';
            mysql_free_result($tempResult);
        }
        echo 'Count: ' . $i . '<br />';
        $query = "select * from table_test LIMIT $i, 2";
        $tempResult = mysql_query($query) or die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
        echo 'Temp Result: ' . $tempResult .' <br />';
        $i  = $i + 2;
        $result .= $tempResult;
    } while (mysql_num_rows($tempResult) > 0);



    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $myrow['col1'] . ' + ' . $myrow['col2'] . 
' + ' . $myrow['col3'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why? Why bother with the limit and the loop if you want to fetch all the rows anyway?

Comment: +1 for posting such amusing question!

Comment: Due to the database being too large to execute the query in one go so I need to split up the number of rows that it retrieves from the database.

Comment: you cannot combine two resources , you can combine their result set
you trying to combine resource ($result .= $tempResult;) so its becomes a sting

Comment: What's wrong with selecting whole database? what's the point in just echoing values? who is supposed to read them?

Comment: If the database is too large to execute the query in one go, then displaying all results is unfeasible by any means... I don't ever want to see a web page with that many billions and billions of records

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a result array? For example something like this:

```
$tempResult = "";
$i = 0;
$resultArray = array();
$result = null;
do
{
    if (is_resource($tempResult))
    {
        echo 'Cleared Result <br />';
        mysql_free_result($tempResult);
    }
    echo 'Count: ' . $i . '<br />';
    $query = "select * from table_test LIMIT $i, 2";
    $tempResult = mysql_query($query) or die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    $resultArray = merge($resultArray, mysql_fetch_array($tempResult));
    echo 'Temp Result: ' . $tempResult .' <br />';
    $i  = $i + 2;
} while (mysql_num_rows($tempResult) > 0);



while ($resultArray as $myRow)
{
    echo $myrow['col1'] . ' + ' . $myrow['col2'] . 
 ' + ' . $myrow['col3'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a single loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from such an *unusual*  question we can only guess the right answer.

My bet:
Your goal is to do some calculations on the data stored in the table.
And you are going to do it in the PHP script instead of the proper way of calculating using database facilities.
So, it's better you would do all the calculations in one query.

Anyway,
It is always a good practice to ask a *core* question, a root problem, instead of a question related to some unusual way you choose to solve it.
Once you ask this one, you will get complete and professional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just print the results in the first loop?

```
$i = 0;
do
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_test LIMIT $i, 2";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $myrow['col1'] . ' + ' . $myrow['col2'] . ' + ' . $myrow['col3'] . ' <br />';
    }
    $i = $i + mysql_affected_rows();
} while (mysql_affected_rows() > 1);
echo 'Count: ' . $i . '<br />';
```

But really, this method just seems like a way to add additional overhead to fetching rows from the database.